# Apollo 15: when did the astronauts manually move the LRV?

Tags: apollo-program, lunar-rover, apollo-15

In [Chapter 9](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a15/a15mr-9.htm) of the Apollo 15 Mission Report it says:

> In the soft, loose soil at the Apollo lunar surface experiment package site, one occurrence of wheel spin was corrected by manually moving the rover to a new surface.

I'm assuming that this means both astronauts lifted & carried the rover. Does anyone know when (or during which EVA) this happened? I went through the [Apollo 15 Lunar Surface Journal](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a15/a15.html) transcripts (focusing on the activities near the ALSEP), but I couldn't find this particular event.

Comment: Or did they just push it a bit?

Comment: Not sure - but if a wheel slips, lifting & carrying it (which the LRV was designed for) seems simpler in lunar gravity than pushing it.

Comment: recalling winters in South Dakota 50 years ago... sometimes is was easier to pick up the end of a small car to lift a pair of wheels out of holes they dug rather than push the car out. Pushing required foot traction which was often hard to achieve on snow covered ice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up getting in touch with the Apollo Lunar Surface Journal folks. Of all the events happening near the ALSEP site, the one that best matches this description is when they try to park the LRV down-Sun at the beginning of EVA 3 (around the [164:06:16](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a15/a15.coreextract.html#:%7E:text=164%3A06%3A16%20Irwin%3A%20Kind%20of%20dug%20in%20there!) mark).

However, David Scott managed to drive the rover out of that situation and parked it in a different location. They did not need to lift the rover or carry it themselves.